# How to print a semicolon (;) without using a semicolon in the program?

Tags: c++, c

I was asked by an interviewer to write code to print a semicolon without using a semicolon in the code.   How is this even possible?

Comment: Use an ascii code: http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/semicolon-ascii-code-59.html

Comment: This question is far too broad for *stackoverflow*, there are an infinite number of ways of printing a `;` without explicitly stating it in the source.

Comment: Some ideas: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/262/print-1-to-1000-in-c-without-semi-colons

Comment: Actually, since after all `cout`s and `printf`s you must write a semicolon, there is no way.

Comment: @enedil: look at my link

Comment: it's only broad if you know the answer.  OP clearly doesn't so we should enlighten rather than scold him

Comment: Well, I think that professional and enthusiast developers should know already that 99.99% of processors handle only binary instructions and data, and so a better question would be 'How to print a semicolon (;) using a processor that does not understand what a semicolon is. How is this even possible?'.

Comment: @RobertLevy SO does not exist for "games" and "contests"

Comment: It's an honest question, not a contest.  OP clearly wasn't aware that characters could be represented in other ways.  That was probably a good hint to the interviewer that OP is an inexperienced dev but we can still enlighten him.

Comment: @RobertLevy: It's an honest question that's too broad. Yes, we _can_ enlighten/help him but (guess what) this is not a helpdesk where we must go to any lengths possible to ensure that the OP gets his help.

Comment: Use bash script. Or use a macro instead of `;` and pass the definition at compile time `gcc -DEND_OF_C_LINE=; prog.c`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is non-constructive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this code :

```
int main()
{
    if(printf("%c",59)) //59 is ascii value of semicolon
    {}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't believe there's any 100% portable way to do this.

The following should work, with well defined behavior, for any conforming hosted C implementation that uses an ASCII-based or EBCDIC-based character encoding:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    if ('z' - 'a' == 25) {
        if (printf("%c\n", 59)) { }
    }
    else {
        if (printf("%c\n", 94)) { }
    }
}
```

I believe it's also valid C++, though not *good* C++ (I'd use `std::cout` and change `(void)` to `()`).

Notes:

- The `#include <stdio.h>` is necessary to avoid undefined behavior on the `printf` calls in C90. In C99 or later, calling `printf` with no visible declaration is a constraint violation.
- The `'\n'` is necessary to avoid undefined behavior on *some* implementations. It is implementation-defined whether a text stream requires a `'\n'` at the end of the last line. For an implementation where it is required, failing to provide one has undefined behavior.
- In C90, omitting a `return` statement causes `main` to return an undefined termination status to the environment. In C99 or later, it's equivalent to `return 0;`.
- The `('z' - 'a' == 25)` test is intended to detect ASCII vs. EBCDIC. In ASCII, the 26 lowercase letters are contiguous; in EBCDIC, they're not. This program will fail for an implementation that uses a character set that's not compatible with either ASCII or EBCDIC. Adding a few more tests could allow for such character sets to be detected, but there's no good way to handle them (unless you happen to know how `';'` is encoded). I've never heard of a C implementation that uses a character set that's not compatible with either ASCII or EBCDIC (at least as far as these specific characters are concerned), so this shouldn't be a problem in practice.
- I haven't tested this on an EBCDIC implementation. The value `94` for `;` is derived from [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC).

Of course there's no good reason to do this other than as an interesting puzzle. Restrictions like "don't use semicolons" make no sense in real-world programming. Even if your semicolon key is broken, you can copy-and-paste a semicolon from some other source until you can repair or replace your keyboard. But perhaps this program would be useful if you need to generate a semicolon that you can copy-and-paste. Fortunately most operating systems should let you edit, compile, and run a simple C program without requiring the use of the semicolon key.

Comment: good C++ would probably use a semicolon and not an empty block though :P

Comment: @djechlin: *chuckle* -- but "good" code in any language needs to solve the problem it's supposed to solve.

Comment: can you reliably predict a character near semicolon? e.g.':' - 1

Comment: what if you output the program  "int main() { return 0$char }" where $char iterates over 1,...,255, try compiling it, and see which one compiles.

Comment: @djechlin: No. The standard guarantees only that `'0'`..`'9'` are contiguous, and that all members of the basic execution character set are non-negative. You could map out all members of the basic execution character set other than `';'` but that would only narrow down the possible values of `';'` to a few possibilities. (In practice, assuming either ASCII or EBCDIC probably covers 100% of real-world implementations.)

Comment: Apparently the people who upvoted this didn't notice the missing right parentheses or the incorrect ASCII value for `';'`. (I just fixed it.)

Answer (score 4):

Try this. Working in both C++ and in C (C99 mode):

```
int main( void )
{
    if(putchar(59)){}
}
```

**Explanation:** Use ASCII code for semicolon which is `59` and to avoid semicolon put the statement `putchar(59)` in an `if`'s conditional expression with empty body. As the conditional expression evaluated it will print `;`. Here note that the return type of `main` is `int` but I am returning nothing to avoid using `;` in `return` statement because you can omit `return 0;` from `main` as per C99 specification.
See the running code here: [C99](http://ideone.com/Q2ukZh), [C++](http://ideone.com/2ElHLS).

Comment: I find your lack of parenthesis disturbing.

Comment: @Quentin; That disturbance was just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

What about this (a more C++ish version):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
while ((std::cout<<static_cast<char>(59))== nullptr){}

}
```

?

(On [ideone](http://ideone.com/zCBnae) apparently no errors)

Or should it be more creative ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Three ways I know of to get the same effect as

```
printf(";");
putchar(';');
printf("%c",';');
```

are (corresponding) as follow

```
printf("\u003B");
putchar(0x3B);
printf("%c",0x3B);
```

Comment: Your are not suppose to use semicolon(;) in the code.

Comment: Do you mean not end a statement?

Comment: You missed the whole point of the question!! Other answers managed it.